Using apply in polars
I am trying to create a new column using apply in polars.
For this, I tried the following operation:
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col("AH_PROC_REALIZADO")
    .apply(get_procedure_description)
    .alias("proced_descr")
)

But I'm getting the error:

AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'apply'

The function I am trying to apply looks as follows.
def get_procedure_description(cod):
    proceds = {
        '41612': 'CIRURGIA ONCOLOGICA',
        '30401': 'RADIOTERAPIA',
        ...
    }

    for proced in proceds.keys():
        if cod[: len(proced)] == proced:
            return proceds[proced]
        
    return None


pl.Expr.apply was deprecated in favour of pl.Expr.map_elements in Polars release 0.19.0. Recently, pl.Expr.apply was removed in the release of Polars 1.0.0.
You can adapt your code to the new version as follows.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("AH_PROC_REALIZADO")
    .map_elements(get_procedure_description, return_dtype=pl.String)
    .alias("proced_descr")
)


If you really want to apply python function then you can use map_elements(). However, using native polars expression is always preferrable.
In your case I'd suggest to look at replace() or replace_strict().
If you would want to just search by AH_PROC_REALIZADO column you could use simple replace_strict():
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "AH_PROC_REALIZADO": ["30408", "410010065", "410010111", "XXXX"]
})

┌───────────────────┐
│ AH_PROC_REALIZADO │
│ ---               │
│ str               │
╞═══════════════════╡
│ 30408             │
│ 410010065         │
│ 410010111         │
│ XXXX              │
└───────────────────┘

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("AH_PROC_REALIZADO")
    .replace_strict(proceds, default=None)
    .alias("proced_descr")
)

┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ AH_PROC_REALIZADO ┆ proced_descr                   │
│ ---               ┆ ---                            │
│ str               ┆ str                            │
╞═══════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 30408             ┆ QUIMIOTERAPIA                  │
│ 410010065         ┆ MASTECTOMIA SIMPLES            │
│ 410010111         ┆ SETORECTOMIA / QUADRANTECTOMIA │
│ XXXX              ┆ null                           │
└───────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘

The problem with your use case is that, as far as I understand, you want to search by prefix of the strings in AH_PROC_REALIZADO column. In that case you could probably adjust the solution to:

itertools.groupby() to transform proceds dictionary into dictionary of dictionaries where high level keys are length of the key.
replace_strict() to search for product description.
coalesce() to combine results into final column.

from itertools import groupby

mappings = {k: dict(g) for k, g in groupby(proceds.items(), lambda x: len(x[0]))}

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "AH_PROC_REALIZADO": ["30408_____", "410010065_____", "410010111____", "XXXX"]
})

┌───────────────────┐
│ AH_PROC_REALIZADO │
│ ---               │
│ str               │
╞═══════════════════╡
│ 30408_____        │
│ 410010065_____    │
│ 410010111____     │
│ XXXX              │
└───────────────────┘

df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.col("AH_PROC_REALIZADO").str.head(k).replace_strict(m, default=None) for k, m in mappings.items()
    )
    .alias("proced_descr")
)

┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ AH_PROC_REALIZADO ┆ proced_descr                   │
│ ---               ┆ ---                            │
│ str               ┆ str                            │
╞═══════════════════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ 30408_____        ┆ QUIMIOTERAPIA                  │
│ 410010065_____    ┆ MASTECTOMIA SIMPLES            │
│ 410010111____     ┆ SETORECTOMIA / QUADRANTECTOMIA │
│ XXXX              ┆ null                           │
└───────────────────┴────────────────────────────────┘

